# SQL Calculated Field Efficiency

Tags: sql-server, performance, calculated-columns, calculated-field

My database has GUIDs as primary keys, this has been done to enforce uniqueness across multiple systems. (yeah I know 16 bytes per row per table overhead there are other options but company choice)

To make the tables a bit friendlier I have added calculated fields, so if you do a select like

```
SELECT * FROM Products
```

You would not only get the column with the foreign key, but a friendly field associated with it.

e.g.
CompanyGUID (Stored field), CompanyName (Calculated field)

The calculated field runs via a scalar function such as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [mySchema].[udf_CompanyNameFromGUID] (@GUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Return NVARCHAR(MAX)
        SELECT  @Return = CompanyName
        FROM    mySchema.Companies
        WHERE   CompanyGUID = @GUID
        RETURN @Return
    END
```

I should point out that these look ups are always against the primary key/clustered index so are individually as fast as I can make them.

Now while this has lots of advantages for when we are tracking back problems, and doesn't have any impact on main usage efficiency (calculated fields not queried so no impact) when we do query a large table, it does take a while to do the lookups.  I don't want to sacrifice the extra data I am looking up , and I don't want to store it directly in the table (waste of data and would need maintaining).  I've considered building views for each table, but that seems like overkill and I'd rather not have to double up on the effort.

I'm sure I'm not the only person who works like this, so I'd like to know if anyone has a more efficient way of doing this?  These fields are only used by people looking directly at the database, and all stored procedures etc. are all coded fully with indexed links etc so main running efficiency is fine, just debugging.  Not a big problem, but if there is a better solution I'd love to hear it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you add calculated columns to your tables using a scalar function to make it easier for a developer? Shouldn't they just learn how to write a join? Seems like typing that join would be less effort than what you are trying to do.

Comment: To be honest I'm tracing data on here as much as anyone else, The more intuitive it is the better.  All the guys (and the one girl) who spend time in the data are quite capable of writing the joins, its just having to do it again and again and again every time they look.  I'd rather do it once and not have to do it again.

Comment: Or alternatively write a view that does the joins for them. Wrapping this in a scalar UDF will guarantee poor performance quite quickly. It will force all the lookups to use RBAR nested loops plus have the various problems associated with scalar UDFs.

Comment: Yeah, I used the views approach in a previous environment, but was trying not to add the bloat here.  We used it before because we allowed the client access to a schema of views that we pre-optimised for them for their SSRS reporting.  The last thing we wanted was a client trying to write queries no matter how tight our database was.

Answer (score 2):

Your main performance problem is not caused by lookups, it's due to `SCALAR FUNCTION` use.

Scalar function is invoked for every row, and is not gratis by itself, but multiplicated for the number of rows you have great performance impact.

May be `view` is a solution in your case: it does not require any additional space as it's just a code that will be expanded when you use the view, and inside a view just JOIN your table with `mySchema.Companies`:

```
create view dbo.MyView as
select * -- put here your columns of interest including CompanyName
from dbo.YourTable
     join  mySchema.Companies
         on CompanyGUID = @GUID;
```

Comment: Yeah, I used the views approach in a previous environment, but was trying not to add the bloat here. We used it before because we allowed the client access to a schema of views that we pre-optimised for them for their SSRS reporting. The last thing we wanted was a client trying to write queries no matter how tight our database was.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your problem. If you don't want your client to use the table directly just deny select on it while leave select permission on a view

Comment: The clients are already denied access, this was just an example.  This is only for our internal use, mainly for when non-dba's need to track down data issues.  Why can't I see a product, why do I get this price.  While I think its fair to ask them to write their own queries, I'd rather have them spending their time more productively if I can come up with a better alternative.  +1 for the answer, but not quite what I'm looking for.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendations:

1. For `companyGUID` column, you can generate and use `NEWSEQUENTIALID` instead of `NEWID`, it reduces fragmentation. and increase index performance.
2. You can make CompanyName column persisted by adding `PERSISTED` option.

Comment: The OP stated that they are using guids as a way of ensuring uniqueness across systems. sequentialid would render this impossible. Actually a uniqueidentifier is not horrible for a primary key but it is not a good choice as the clustered index. As you stated the fragmentation goes crazy.

Comment: RE: 2 they won't be able to make this persisted. It is not deterministic.

Comment: I had considered Persisting the column, which does have a performance boost, but it also has an impact on the amount of storage required.  While not massive, these fields are only used for debugging or tracing data.  Nice to see someone following the same path as me though. Thanks for the option.